# Can www.example.com/node/123 be used as a canonical url?

Tags: 7, uri

We are sharing some of our content with partners and want to include a canonical reference to the pages on our Drupal site.

I like the idea of using `www.example.com/node/$nid` for the simplicity of it, but I don't know whether it is acceptable for a canonical url to be redirected (as is commonly done with clean urls, path_auto, redirect, etc)?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, the answer is yes, you can add node/nid as canonical url, drupal already take care of this. For other option you can check module like metatag. Also check this link http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permanently redirecting the `canonical` URL is [allowed, but discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13222711/1591669) by [RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3):

> To better ensure that applications properly handle the canonical link relation, administrators ought to consider the following guidelines:
>
> […]
>
> Avoid designating the target (canonical) as:
>
> […]
>
> The source IRI of a permanent redirect (for HTTP, this refers to 300 and 301 response codes defined in Sections 10.3.1 and 10.3.2 of [RFC2616]